# Finding Distance using multiple Lat Long points stored in SQLite table

Tags: android, sqlite, google-maps

I am new at SQLite (using n Android). my question is i have a table which has multiple latitude and longitude points, corresponding to the path traveled by a person. means first entry of longitude and latitude is when person started moving and last point shows where person stopped.

How can I get the values of lat long from the database and find the distance person traveled.

My table contains the following attributes-

1. numbering auto increment, by which i want to sort entries and calculate distance.
2. Latitude
3. Longitude
4. Accuracy

Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not extracting any data for now. m just inserting lat long values.

Comment: Can you show your code that inserts the lat lon values?

Comment: public void insertLocationRow(double lat, double lon,float accuracy) {

   long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();

  ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
  cv.put(COLUMN_LATITUDE, Double.toString(lat));
  cv.put(COLUMN_LONGITUDE, Double.toString(lon));
  cv.put(COLUMN_ACCURACY, accuracy);
  cv.put(COLUMN_UNIX_TIMESTAMP, timestamp);
  Log.i("Location values inserted in database", "" + lat + "" + lon + "" + accuracy + "" + timestamp);
  getWritableDatabase().insert(LOCATION_TABLE, null, cv);}

Comment: MyDbHelper insertLocation = new MyDbHelper(context);
    insertLocation.insertLocationRow(lat, lon, acc);
    Log.i("Location", "" + lat + "" + lon + ""
      + acc);

Comment: Ignoring the altitude will introduce (very small) errors.